# How to change native Resolution on MBP 2015 running Mojave?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, performance, system-settings

My problem is I would like to change the native resolution of the built-in screen of my MBPR 2015 running Mojave to 1920 * 1080. The thing is I don't want the output to be scaled, I just want this resolution to gain performance. Any way to achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Changing the resolution is unlikely to improve performance.

Comment: The native resolution of the display on a MBP is what it is and cannot be changed, only scaled.

Comment: are you sure about that ? I am sure there must be some kind of hidden file to modify the native resolution, or at least a trick to make the built in screen behave like an external one...

Answer (score 1):

While you can't "change the native resolution", you can use the [displaymode](https://github.com/p00ya/displaymode) command line tool to change *to* the native resolution instead of scaled resolutions.

Download the displaymode binary from the "releases" section on github, and extract it if necessary.  Then from Terminal.app, `cd` to the directory the `displaymode` file is in and run:

```
./displaymode t 1920 1080
```

You can also run:

```
./displaymode d
```

to get a list of supported resolutions.